Problems importing iPad text with quotes into an Access database
I use DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed successfully to import text from an iPad to windows via iCloud drive. The single and double quotes don't convert correctly.
Example:

let's try a "typical" use of ' and " character

converts to

letâ€™s try a â€œtypicalâ€ use of â€˜ and â€œ character

Note that the conversion for the double quote is different between the leading and trailing double quote making post import corrections difficult.
I've tried various Code Page Id's and no joy'. e.g.
DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "TestSpec", Txt_tableName, "C:\Users\josmi\iCloudDrive\Events\" & txt_fileName, 0, , 65001 

which is utf_8. I tried with no code page and many others without success.

Are you sure your text file is UTF8?  If you open it in a text editor what does it detect as the format?

Perhaps see other questions re the “curly” double quote, “, being (mis)interpreted as â€œ. I agree with the advice regarding first viewing the text file in some other text editor app to see if the file has already been corrupted. I might even do a hex dump to really see what is there, byte by byte. Once we know how the curly double quotes are really represented in the file, then we can tackle your import question.

I'd be willing to bet that your "TestSpec" import specification has "Code Page:" set to "Western European (Windows)" and that is taking precedence over the 65001 in the TransferText statement,

Access's support for UTF-8 has been shoddy, at least last time I tried to use it. I'd convert to UTF-16 first, then do the import.

@ErikA — "support for UTF-8 has been shoddy" — I agree, but converting the file to UTF-16 won't help if the import spec is mis-configured as I suspect. I have verified that TransferText will import the quotation marks correctly if the import spec uses "Unicode (UTF-8)".

Gord, the input spec was Western European. After some trial and error I used UTF-8 in my TestSpec and it worked if I imported from Access External Data. However, My program's  DoCmd.TransferText Still won't work I think becasue the default import it Western European and I can't find a way to change that.

Sounds like maybe you forgot to save your change to the import spec after you switched from "Western European (Windows)" to "Unicode (UTF-8)". You need to click the "Save As…" button to make the change permanent. (p.s. remember to use @ for notifications here.)

@Gord Fixed Import Spec switched to UTF-8 Solved the problem. Thanks
